# Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Often when I plot in matplotlib, I get graphs like this:

[image: frequency response running along top edge]

You can't see the function because it runs against the edge of the plot.

Is there any way to *automatically* add some margin in these cases, so that they look like this:

[image: frequency response with tiny amount of noise]

Comment: Ooh, you could add small amounts of noise to ensure that it's always slightly above 0?  Something like `h += randn(len(h)) * spacing(abs(h)) * 100000`?

Answer (score 19):

You can use `ax.margins()` to set the [margins](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=xlim#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins). Example:

```
In [1]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()

In [2]: ax.plot(np.arange(10), '-o')
Out[2]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x302fb50>]
```

[image: without margin]

```
In [1]: fig, ax = plt.subplots()

In [2]: ax.margins(0.05)

In [3]: ax.plot(np.arange(10), '-o')
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x302fb50>]
```

[image: with margin]

You can also set only the x- or the y-margin. However it doesn't seem to be a `matplotlibrc` option so that you can simply make this the default behaviour (so it isn't fully automatically). I opened a [github issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1766) to request this.

Comment: Hi, any hint on how to do this but on UIAxes from App Designer?