# matplotlib modify autoscaling rules

Tags: matplotlib

when plotting, matplotlib sets automatically the scales from the data content being plotted. But it seems the limits on both axes are always equal to the maxima from the data given to be plotted. It makes markers of data reaching maxima being copped. I would like to change this behaviour so that it leaves some space at the four sides of the plot whatever the marker size. At least, is there a way to simply set a static, user defined margin?

an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(np.arange(10) ** 2, 's', ms = 20)
```

this example clearly shows 3 data points being cropped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(copied almost directly from [How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib/15376411#15376411))

You want `margins` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins)

ex

```
ax.margins(y=.1, x=.1)
```

Also see [Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph/14498142#14498142)

Comment: ok, in fact I searched a bit before starting this post, but it seems I searched with the wrong key words. This solution is good but it seems it can't set left and right or top and bottom margins independently.

Comment: @user1850133 I am pretty sure that is the case (that you can't set top, bottom, left, right individually).  If you would really like that maybe submit a feature request to the github, or just do your axis limits by hand.

Comment: I just tried to go on github, it seems a bit complicated, I'll take some time to submit my request.

Comment: Once you have an account go to https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues?sort=updated&state=open and hit the big green button in the top right