# Last graph marker in matplotlib not showing fully

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm new to matplotlib. My graph in matplotlib doesn't show the last marker fully. I've tried increasing the figure size and nothing changes. I need to extend the figure so that it shows the last marker and also extend the line past the marker. Here's my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x = np.array([1,2,5,10,15,20])
    y = np.array([0.049,0.080,0.123,0.166,0.209,0.335])

    A = np.vstack([x, np.ones(len(x))]).T
    m, c = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0]

    x = np.array([0,1,2,5,10,15,20])
    y = np.array([c,0.049,0.080,0.123,0.166,0.209,0.335])

    plt.plot(x, y, 'r*', label='Original data', markersize=7)
    plt.plot(x, m*x + c, 'b', label='Fitted line')
    fig = plt.figure(1)
    fig.set_size_inches(9,8)
    fig.suptitle('THE GRAPH OF ABSORBANCE AGAINST CONCENTRATION',fontsize=20)
    plt.xlabel('CONCENTRATION',fontsize=15)
    plt.ylabel('ABSORBANCE',fontsize=15)
    plt.grid()
    fig.savefig('graph.jpg')
```

Would really appreciate your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph?lq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003263/matplotlib-modify-autoscaling-rules/16003292#16003292

Comment: Did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 2):

(mostly copied from [How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib?lq=1))

You want `margins` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins)

ex

```
ax.margins(y=.1, x=.1)
```

Also see [Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph/14498142#14498142)

`matplotlib` 1.3.x will include the `rcParam` values `axes.xmargin` and `axes.ymargin` to set a none-zero margin (code for it is in master already).