# Adjust separation between axes and data on graph, Matplotlib, Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting line graphs in matplotlib and have an axis on each side of the graph (forming a box).  The automatic axis scaling in matplotlib makes these axes sit at all the extremes of the data that I'm plotting.  So, for example, if I were to plot a circle the axes would form a square box touching the circle in the middle of each side.

Is there a way of setting the axes to leave a certain gap between the axes and the data?  At the moment if I turn off autoscaling I get a nice gap on one side but not another.

I'd like to do it without manually setting the axes ranges since I'm writing one program to plot a lot of graphs and I don't want to have to set the ranges for each graph.

Thanks.

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib/15376411#15376411

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897864/avoid-points-on-edges-of-plots-when-the-last-x-value-equals-the-tick/16898296#16898296

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136748/last-graph-marker-in-matplotlib-not-showing-fully/16136804#16136804

Comment: @JoeKington I only mined my own answers, I assume you have also answered this a couple of times....

Comment: I'd been searching for the answer with the wrong keywords and found the answer in one of those duplicates.  Thanks.

Comment: @tcaswell - Yeah, it's definitely a frequently asked question.

Comment: "I assume you have also answered this a couple of times"

You mean asked?  I've only asked this once, but thanks for all your answers.

Comment: @user3087409 That was directed at Joe Kington (signified by the @ at the beginning).  Don't worry, your fine.