# Markers at the border of the fig cannot show completely using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

What I expect is like this:
[image]

What I get is  this:
[image]
How to show all the marker completely without extending ax?
People have given solution which extends ax([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136748/last-graph-marker-in-matplotlib-not-showing-fully#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136748/last-graph-marker-in-matplotlib-not-showing-fully#_=_))? Is this the only way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried turning off the clipping? 
Try

```
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', clip_on=False)
```