# Avoid points on edges of plots when the last x-value equals the tick

Tags: python, matplotlib

Every time I try to plot some points the last point ends up right on the edge of the plot:

[image]

Note the point circled in red. Is it possible to avoid this? I'd like to have some space between the last point plotted and the right plot edge.

My desired output would be:

[image]

Which I obtained increasing the last x value by a tiny amount. I'd like to find a way of plotting that automatically handles this and that doesn't depend on the size of the values(e.g. if I was plotting really small float values then even the smallest change would be significant and the output wouldn't reflect the data)

I'm plotting using:

```
figure(1)
#X[-1] += 0.0001    #ugly way of obtaining some space at the right
errorbar(X, Y, yerr=error, fmt='bo')
```

Comment: can you set the `xlim` on the axis?

Comment: Would setting the `xlim` as `((X[max]-x[max-1]/2)` be good enough? I thought i read something about a padding option once but I am still searching for that

Comment: The function you want is `ax.margins`

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003263/matplotlib-modify-autoscaling-rules/16003292#16003292

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136748/last-graph-marker-in-matplotlib-not-showing-fully/16136804#16136804

Comment: Tcaswell is correct, you want `margins`, the `padding` that I was thinking of refers to the padding between sub plots.

Comment: @tcaswell `margins` is perfect. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. I find strange that it isn't mentioned in the "tutorial", while I think it's something worth mentioning in the basics.

Comment: Please suggest edits to the tutorial an github;)

Answer (score 2):

(copied almost directly from [How to autoscale y axis in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375791/how-to-autoscale-y-axis-in-matplotlib/15376411#15376411))

You want `margins` [doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.margins)

ex

```
ax.margins(y=.1, x=.1)
```

Also see [Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph/14498142#14498142)

Comment: I just realized that this doesn't do exactly what I want, because it adds margin also on the bottom and the left. I want the origin to stay exactly at the bottom left corner if possible.

Comment: As I said I'd like the origin to be exactly on the bottom left corner. Putting `y=0` the origin is at the correct height, but a bit on the right. I believe `margins` cannot be used to obtain exactly what I want, since they margins can only be symmetric, while I want them only on the right.

Comment: @Bakuriu Sorry, read your comment too fast (read 'left' as 'top').  I don't know of an automatic way to do that.

Comment: @Bakuriu I apologize for being snippy.

Comment: This was the solution for my problem.