# Autoscale non-numeric axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

`plt.margins` works great for autoscaling axes that containing data in the form of int or float values, as explained in [Add margin when plots run against the edge of the graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14493334/add-margin-when-plots-run-against-the-edge-of-the-graph/14498142#14498142). However, it does not seem to work when plotting other values, such as string labels or a pandas data frame index:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,3,2,6])
ax = df.plot(marker='o', ls='')
ax.margins(0.05)
```

[image]

Only the y-axis is rescaled, not the x-axis Naturally, there is still an x-range, and setting it manually to reasonable values with `ax.set_xlim()`, reveals the truncated data points in the plot above:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,3,2,6])
ax = df.plot(marker='o', ls='')
ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_xlim(-0.1, 3.1)
```

[image]

Is it possible to autoscale an axes with string labels or a pandas dataframe index? If so, how would I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

You know the scale of the x-axis, `0` to the length of your data frame minus `1`.

```
ax.set_xlim(-0.1, len(df) - 0.9)
```

Would be an appropriate "`autoscale`" function.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

df = pd.DataFrame([random.randrange(1, 10) for i in range(random.randrange(5, 15))])
ax = df.plot(marker='o', ls='')
ax.margins(0.05)
ax.set_xlim(-0.1, len(df) - 0.9)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own `autoscale()` function.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def automargin(ax=None, marginx=0.1, marginy=0.1, relative=False):
    if ax == None:
        ax=plt.gca()
    xlim=ax.get_xlim()
    ylim = ax.get_ylim()
    if relative:
        dx = xlim[1] - xlim[0]; dy = ylim[1] - ylim[0]
        ax.set_xlim([xlim[0]-dx*marginx, xlim[1]+dx*marginx])
        ax.set_ylim([ylim[0]-dy*marginy, ylim[1]+dy*marginy])
    else:
        ax.set_xlim([xlim[0]-marginx, xlim[1]+marginx])
        ax.set_ylim([ylim[0]-marginy, ylim[1]+marginy])


df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [0,1,2,3], "y" : [9,4,7,5]})
ax = df.plot(marker='o', ls='')

#Try some of the following:
automargin()
automargin(ax)
automargin(ax, relative=True)
automargin(ax, marginy=0.5)
automargin(ax, marginx=1, marginy=0.5)
automargin(ax, marginx=0.05, marginy=0.05, relative=True)

plt.show()
```